# Not able to align the elements in-line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a footer for my website.

I want 2 divs and one list to be inline in this footer. But  that is not happening. I used the css the CSS Property `display:inline-block`. What happens is that the `div`s get aligned but the `list` element just shifts a bit down.

Here is the jsFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/tw2Wp/2/.
If you see the JSfiddle, you will that the three divs with class `footerContents` are not aligned in-line.

Could someone please explain me why this is happening? Is it right thing to use `inline-block` for this thing or is there some better way(I'm sure that there is)?

Comment: You can try this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NGcNK/, I thinks the reason because of margin for your 3 class `footerContents` of you. I change your `display: inline-block` to `float: left` to remove this difference (margin of each item)

Comment: @Stiger, Notice tht when you will change the width of the screen the width of the footer also changes . ho to adjust that?

Comment: the width of footer change because this css property `width: 100%` of `#footer`. If you don't want this, maybe you should fix it in px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you use the css3 flexbox module, like this:

#### HTML

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="footerContents">
       ...
     </div>

     <ul class="footerContents">
        ...
     </ul>

     <div class="footerContents">
        ...
     </div>
</div>
<div>Copyright © </div>
```

#### CSS

```
#footer {
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#666;
  background-image:url(footer_shade.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:50% 0;
  border-top:1px solid #FFF;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:'Bree Serif',serif;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:20px;

  display:-moz-box;
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-box-pack: justify; 
  -moz-box-pack: justify; 
  -ms-flex-pack: justify; 
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footerContents {
  width:200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding:5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: red;

  -moz-flex-box:1;
  -webkit-flex-box:1;
  -ms-flex:1 1 200px;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 200px;
  flex:1 1 200px;
}
```

Please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/yspcj). and some about the flexbox, if you want to know,please will click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/blog/tags/157.html) and [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/).

Answer (score 2):

Please add `vertical-align` to `.footerContents`:

```
.footerContents {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: top; /* <<< */
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/esFh8/)

Comment: I thought vertical-align property is only meant for images.

Comment: vertical-align property is used for inline-block and table and img elements

Comment: Ok right. I got it. Could you help me with one more thing. Why is this footer width changing when I change the size of the screen?

Comment: please use the media queries for your footer. you can use the responsive design for your web sites:http://www.w3cplus.com/blog/tags/79.html

Comment: The page is in some other language, I dont understand anything. Is there an english version?

Comment: You can use the css3 flexbox module. it is very strong,but not support the ie9-. If you need, i will create a demo for you.

Comment: Ok, you can create it, please. But then what about IE9.?

Comment: hi,Navneet Saini:I have created the demo with the flexbox, would you like it.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to read about flex-box model. I wasn't aware about it. Should I change my whole website design now?

Comment: you can use the white-space for the footer.please view the new demo.http://codepen.io/airen/pen/zjBCv

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to float the elements rather than using `inline-block`, see working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tw2Wp/2/

Note that I also added an extra div with the class `clear` which will clear the floats. By doing this your background will appear again. Because of the floated elements the parent div doesn't have a clue how large it should be (so it's height 0).

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but then why I cannot use 'inline-block' here?

Comment: I thought `vertical-align` property is only meant for images.. Thanks for your help, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

#### HTML

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="footerContents">
       ...
     </div>

     <ul class="footerContents">
        ...
     </ul>

     <div class="footerContents">
        ...
     </div>
</div>
<div>Copyright © </div>
```

#### CSS

```
#footer {
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#666;
  background-image:url(footer_shade.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:50% 0;
  border-top:1px solid #FFF;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:'Bree Serif',serif;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:20px;
  **white-space: nowrap;**
}

.footerContents {
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding:5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  **vertical-align: top;
  white-space: normal;**
}
```

please view the new [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/zjBCv).